# How is if/while condition evaluated when we use assignments instead of comparison?

Tags: java, if-statement

I discovered this surprising thing while learning OCA/OCP for Java.

Below is the first piece of code of which the if(test condition) part
surprises me.

```
public class BooleanIf {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean b = false;
    System.out.println(Boolean.valueOf(b = true));
    if (b = true)
        System.out.println("true");
    else
        System.out.println("false");
}
```

Now the output of this surprisingly is "true".

I learnt that there has to be a relational condition that returns true or false like `if (a > b)` or `if (a != b)` likewise.

I want to know how it is returning true for this case. Does it call Boolean.valueOf()?

Comment: If you are really learning for the OCPJP, you should know this! If not, please complete the OCAJP first!

Comment: how come this question is being answered by 10k+ users ??? for reall??, i thought it was only low-rep whores like me, that chase these.. hmmm

Comment: @NoRelect Sorry i meant oca and ocp both.

Comment: @GhostCat sorry I was busy. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `=` is assignment operator,
- `==` is comparison operator.

But assignment operator

```
x = y
```

not only *assigns* value from `y` to variable `x`, but it also ***returns*** that value.

Thanks to that we can write code like

```
x = y = z = 1;
//equivalent of:
x = (y = (z = 1));
```

(although it is not recommended as it can be confusing, especially for new Java programmers)

As you see `1` is first assigned to variable `z`, *then* expression `z = 1` *returns* 1 which can be assigned to variable `y`. Then again assigning 1 to `y` returns 1 which can be assigned to variable `x`.

Because of that *returning* mechanism it is possible to write code like `if (b = true)` since `true` will be assigned to `b` and then returned. Since `if(..)` expected boolean for its condition, and found one code compiled fine.

In other words `if(b=true){...}` is very similar to `if(true){b=true; ...}`. This means that such `if` will always execute code from `true` branch (since that is what we ware assigning to `b`).

---

#### BONUS: How to prevent this typo?

- omit `==true` and `==false` parts.

  - In case of `if(b==true)` we can write `if(b)` since `(b == true)` will always give same result as already stored in `b`.
  - In case of `if(b==false)` we can write `if(!b)`.
- use [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) `if(true == b){..}` where value is used before/on left side and variable on right side of `==`.
  Even if by mistake we will write `=` instead of `==` we will end up with `true = b` which will end up as compilation error since we can't *assign* anything to *value* like `true` (just like we can't compile `2=3;` which would attempt to assign 3 to 2 which makes no sense). We can only assign values to *variables*.

Answer (score 2):

this is not a very good practice

`Boolean.valueOf(b = true),` and you should avoid doing such, now regarding the question>

`if (b = true)` is the same as

```
b = true;
if (b)
```

therefore the condition is always met

analog to this.

```
if (b = false)
```

will be never ever executed...

ADditional information:

that kind of typos/mistakes are made by normally junior developers...

some when in the history of the development, it came a solution for that...

the so called JODA-Conditions(called like that as the Master JODA from stars-wars...)

so, the JODA-Conditions will be safe in this case since you can try to do:

```
if (true = b) {
        // code here
    }
```

but this will no compile since the complain:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable,

the controversy is still open about how good idea is that, is the code more readable like that etc etc...,

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by looking at the structure of an `if` statement:

```
if ( <boolean-expression> ) {
    ...
}
```

The `<boolean-expression>` can be any expression that evaluates to `boolean`. Most commonly, this is a logical expression, i.e. an expression with comparison operators and/or some logical operators, such as `&&`, `||`, and `!`.

However, the expression could be a call to a method returning a `boolean`, for example:

```
if (list.isEmpty()) {
    ...
}
```

Next, let's look at an assignment expression. It is an expression with a side effect. The right side gets evaluated and assigned to the left side. The value of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment.

In your case, the assignment is `b = true`, so the value of the expression is `true`. Plugging it into the first part explains why you get the result that you see - `b = true` in

```
if (b = true) {
    ...
}
```

is a valid boolean expression returning `true`, so the code complies and runs correctly. A more common scenario uses an assignment to store the result for future reference, like this:

```
if (b = list.isEmpty()) {
    ...
}
```

This lets you refer to the result of `list.isEmpty()` outside of the conditional, without invoking the method again.

**Note:** Although situations exist when an assignment inside a conditional is a valid practice, it is not common, so one should heavily comment its use.

Answer (score 0):

`if` expects an expression of type boolean.

A boolean variable has type ... boolean.

So, what might probably happen when you put a boolean variable behind an if?