# Why does my program change the boolean value,?

Tags: java

I'm writing a simple program that checks whether a input word can be spelled with input letters. No matter what I input the boolean always changes to true, even when the values in the if statement are not equal.
Is there an easy fix, or should I rewrite the program in a diffrent way ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String letters, word;
    System.out.print("Enter your letters: ");
    letters = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter your word: ");
    word = keyboard.nextLine();
    spellCheck(word, letters);
}

public static void spellCheck(String word, String letters) {
    String w = word.toLowerCase();
    String l = letters.toLowerCase();
    int count = 0;
    boolean check = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++) {
        if (w.length() > l.length()) {
            check = false;
            break;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < l.length(); j++) {
            if (w.charAt(i) == l.charAt(j)) {
                count++;
            }
            if (count == w.length()) {
                check = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (check = true) {
        System.out.println("You can spell " + word + " with " + letters);
    }
    if (check = false) {
        System.out.println("You can't spell " + word + " with " + letters);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There's a difference between check = true and check == true

Comment: You could avoid the whole issue with just `if (check) { ... } else { ... }`. No need for redundant comparisons (much less accidental assignments).

Comment: Related: [How is if/while condition evaluated when we use assignments instead of comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38980041)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Comparisons in java are done with double equals `==`.
If you use just one, you are actually setting the value of something.

But this is a pretty basic java question, hence I recommend you reading a bit more into documentation and basic tutorial :)