# incorrect use of modulus in if statement? Keep getting unexpected type error ( required variable found value)

Tags: java, syntax-error

Im unable to run the below code and get the following message (the arrow points to the modulus symbol):

**error: unexpected type
if ((number % 10) = 0 && (number%9 =0)) {System.out.print("You won $200");}
^
required: variable
found:    value**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = read.nextInt();

        if ((number % 10) = 0 && (number%9 =0)){System.out.print('You won $200');}
        else if (number%4=0 || number%6=0){System.out.print("You won $50");}
        else {System.out.print("Try again");}
```

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator. To check for equality you need to use `==`.

Comment: You probably also meant `||`.

Comment: `%` is not the modulo operator in Java, it's the [_remainder operator_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3). This isn't just nit-picking, it doesn't have the same semantics as `%` in other languages. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239959/modulo-division-vs-remainder-division-java)

Comment: In Java, you should also use `.equals()` instead of `==` for comparison in most cases.

Comment: @Juerrrgen not in this case, though, as only primitives are compared here.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980041/how-is-if-while-condition-evaluated-when-we-use-assignments-instead-of-compariso

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand the difference between an equality `==` and an assignment operator `=`.

**Assignment (`=`)**

This is what one uses to assign values to a variable.

In your `if` condition, you are using this operator where instead you need to compare values using the equality operator.

**Equality (`==`)**

This is what is used to compare between values.

For example, in your `if` condition, you should be using this equality operator `==` to check if `number % 10` is equal to `0`

Comment: In older languages like Pascal the assignment operator is := and comparison = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)

Comment: @Adriaan Koster, A good FYI, but the OP is referring to Java.

Comment: Indeed true. I was not trying to correct your great answer, just to provide some additional info.